# Transforming linear mixed model effect estimate to odds of a predetermined increment of change

Tags: model, linear, odds

I'm studying patient reported outcome in relation to treatment modalities in cancer. To assess the effect of a specific treatment (yes/no) on a specific outcome (normalised to 0-100, repeated measures anually after treatment) I've determined a (lme4)linear mixed model with the outcome as independent variable, treatment as fixed effect and a patient level random intercept in the simplest model. My output provides me with an effect estimate with confidence intervals, describing the effect of the treatment on the outcome, which is nice:).
Now, what if I've established that a 10% change on my 0-100 scale is "clinically sigificant", can I transform my effect estimate from the linear model into an odds ratio of a 10% change ocurring? How would I proceed?

Comment: Hi David, I'm not quite clear what additional benefit you could get from an odds ratio that your effect estimate (and CI) don't give you? While you could use a logistic mixed model to calculate the odds ratio of a >10 point change, this would throw away much of your information. The information contained in your average treatment effect is much richer as it gives the best estimate and the range of most compatible values (which may or may not include clinically significant effects)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input! I agree that the effect estimates that I have are informative, but I also find the odds ratio appealing in explaining my findings. Odds ratios might be more intuitive when publishing or presenting to clinicians.. Maybe I need to get better at explaining my results 